# Is "Today, 800 billion cup of teas is sipped from teabags." correct?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

My English is telling that this is correct but I don't think so.

> Today, 800 billion cup of teas is sipped from teabags.

Comment: Which part is bothering you?

Comment: How do you sip from a teabag?

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence raises several questions.

As you suggest, we talk about **cups of tea** and not **cup of teas**.

It's hard to know what **today** refers to, whether a day, a year or merely the modern era. Whatever the case, 800-billion is a vast number of cups of tea that would require much of the earth's population to spend much of its time drinking tea.

And, as Kate notes, one sips from a cup (or glass or similar) and not from a teabag.

So possibly, somebody meant to say that **Today, people sip 800-billion cups of tea, brewed from tea-bags.